# Make the browser prompt for open/save the file instead of downloading immediately

Tags: java, httpresponse

I have a download Service which can be used to download files of any extension (.pdf/.png/.xls/.zip etc). I want the browser to prompt for save/open file.

```
File file = new FileService().downloadMetadataFile(context, s3Name);
return Response.ok((Object) file)
               .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName())
               .build();
```

This works fine in firefox but in other browsers like chrome or IE it directly downloads the file .If I set inline instead of attachment it directly opens the file in browser doesn't download.

```
File file = new FileService().downloadMetadataFile(context, s3Name);
return Response.ok((Object) file)
               .header("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + file.getName())
               .build();
```

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible. The user configures his browser to either prompt for a download location, or download in a Downloads folder.

Comment: Is there any other way of doing this. I am using jquery and html5 in client side.