# Is there any option to open "Ask where to save each file before downloading" of browser using ASP.NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-handling, asp.net-core-3.1

While downloading any file from the ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, browser should always ask location where to save it?

In the browser we have option namely "Ask where to save each file before downloading" but I want to do it programmatically whenever my application get option on Client Machine.

Comment: So, you want to override the browser setting and prompt where to save file for each file? This is not possible!

Comment: Any particular reason, why it is not possible?

Comment: Because there's no API available from JS that allows you to do so and this would override the user's preferences. I know that if I tell the browser to save all files to my downloads folder. I wouldn't want a website to be able to prompt me where to save it.

Comment: Is there any chance that i can opt where to save the file? Irrespective of touching browser's feature.

Comment: Nope, only the user can do that. It would open up all sorts of security issues. I'm wondering WHY you want to do this.

Comment: Its client requirement that they want a dialogue box which allow them to save file on particular location.

Comment: Don't believe it can be done! Best they can do is ask all their users to enable prompting where to save file each time. I'm willing to be corrected in my assertion but I don't think it's possible unless it's a desktop app instead of an app running in a browser.

Comment: There are a number of questions on SO asking the same, all with the same answer - No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42266918/make-the-browser-prompt-for-open-save-the-file-instead-of-downloading-immediatel
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19679842/prompting-user-to-save-file-using-a-save-as-dialog
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38981701/how-to-prompt-save-as-option-for-user-to-download-file-using-chrome
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8405180/prompt-user-to-save-file-to-a-specific-location

Comment: I think the best you can do is change the name of the file but no way to force the prompt of where to save the file.

Comment: Thanks @phuzi for the prompt help..

Comment: No problem, I guess you're going to have to go back to the client and tell them it's not possible. Depends how attached to the idea they are, perhaps ask them for the reasoning behind it, there may be an alternate solution they haven't considered. Good luck.